# ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, google-play-services, build.gradle

I got a problem as follows, I didn't know how to fix it, please help me. Thank you.

In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends 
on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.13.1]", but isn't being resolved to 
that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

```
Dependency failing: io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.13.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core@[1.13.1], 
but grpc-core version was 1.15.1.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have 
transitive dependencies that lead to the artifact with the issue.

-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded@1.13.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.api:gax-grpc@1.32.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-core@1.15.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-protobuf@1.13.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite@1.13.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc@1.49.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-okhttp@1.15.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.cloud:google-cloud- dialogflow@0.67.0-alpha
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-auth@1.13.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-stub@1.13.1

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with 
./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dependency paths to the 
artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, 
report issues at https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable 
by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your 
build.gradle file.
```

**This is my app gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lin.firebase.dialogbot"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'

    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // DialogFlow SDK depencies
    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'

    // Java v2
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.67.0-alpha'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.15.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my project gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me about this, it made me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried changing the okhttp version in your gradle script to 1.13.1?

Answer (score 3):

Change io.grpc version to '1.13.1' as mentioned below in app's build.gradle.

```
// Java v2
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.67.0-alpha'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.13.1'
```